# Why can't I delete duplicates from this list (of BeautifulSoup HTML) in Python?

Tags: python, duplicates, beautifulsoup

I currently have a list of BeautifulSoup HTML items that I got with the following method call:

```
tables = HTML.findAll("table", {"class": "datadisplaytable"})
```

This simply returns all the tables in the HTML document that match the query. This all great and well, but it returns duplicate tables (as seen below in my output).

I've tried doing this to delete the duplicates:

```
tables = list(set(HTML.findAll("table", {"class": "datadisplaytable"})))
```

And it deletes the duplicates but it doesn't preserve the **order** which I **need**.

So I tried this:

```
holder = []

for item in tables:
    if item not in holder:
        holder.append(item)
```

However, the duplicates still exist. Is the above method not capable of handling BeautifulSoup HTML? If not, how do you delete BeautifulSoup HTML duplicates with preserving the order?

**EDIT:**

```
tables = OrderedDict.fromkeys(HTML.findAll("table", {"class": "datadisplaytable"})).keys()
```

Then when printing, it was duplicate free:

```
for item in tables:
    print "\n\n\n"
    print item
```

But then, when I try to print doing the following, the duplicates are back. Am I going crazy?

```
i = 0
while (i < len(tables)-1):
    print "\n\nitem[i]:   \n", tables[i]
    print "\n\nitem[i+1]:  \n", tables[i+1]

    i += 1
```

Any ideas?

```
item[i]:   
<table class="datadisplaytable" summary="This table lists the scheduled meeting times and assigned instructors for this class.."><caption class="captiontext">Scheduled Meeting Times</caption>
<tbody><tr>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Type</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Time</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Days</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Where</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Date Range</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Schedule Type</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Instructors</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dddefault">Class</td>
<td class="dddefault">2:00 pm - 3:15 pm</td>
<td class="dddefault">MWF</td>
<td class="dddefault">Manchester Hall 241</td>
<td class="dddefault">Jan 13, 2015 - May 07, 2015</td>
<td class="dddefault">Lecture</td>
<td class="dddefault">William H.  Turkett (<abbr title="Primary">P</abbr>)<a href="mailto:turketwh@wfu.edu" target="William H. Turkett"><img align="middle" alt="E-mail" border="0" class="headerImg" height="28" hspace="0" name="web_email" src="/wtlgifs/web_email.gif" title="E-mail" vspace="0" width="28"/></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


item[i+1]:  
<table class="datadisplaytable" summary="This layout table is used to present the schedule course detail"><caption class="captiontext">Linear Algebra I - MTH 121 - C</caption>
<tbody><tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Associated Term:</th>
<td class="dddefault">Spring 2015</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row"><acronym title="Course Reference Number">CRN</acronym>:</th>
<td class="dddefault">19765</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Status:</th>
<td class="dddefault">**Web Registered** on Nov 05, 2014</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Assigned Instructor:</th>
<td class="dddefault">
Jason D. Gaddis<a href="mailto:gaddisjd@wfu.edu" target="Jason D. Gaddis"><img align="middle" alt="E-mail" border="0" class="headerImg" height="28" hspace="0" name="web_email" src="/wtlgifs/web_email.gif" title="E-mail" vspace="0" width="28"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Grade Mode:</th>
<td class="dddefault">Standard Letter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Credits:</th>
<td class="dddefault">    4.000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Level:</th>
<td class="dddefault">Undergraduate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Campus:</th>
<td class="dddefault">Reynolda Campus  (UG)</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


item[i]:   
<table class="datadisplaytable" summary="This layout table is used to present the schedule course detail"><caption class="captiontext">Linear Algebra I - MTH 121 - C</caption>
<tbody><tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Associated Term:</th>
<td class="dddefault">Spring 2015</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row"><acronym title="Course Reference Number">CRN</acronym>:</th>
<td class="dddefault">19765</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Status:</th>
<td class="dddefault">**Web Registered** on Nov 05, 2014</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Assigned Instructor:</th>
<td class="dddefault">
Jason D. Gaddis<a href="mailto:gaddisjd@wfu.edu" target="Jason D. Gaddis"><img align="middle" alt="E-mail" border="0" class="headerImg" height="28" hspace="0" name="web_email" src="/wtlgifs/web_email.gif" title="E-mail" vspace="0" width="28"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Grade Mode:</th>
<td class="dddefault">Standard Letter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Credits:</th>
<td class="dddefault">    4.000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Level:</th>
<td class="dddefault">Undergraduate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="ddlabel" colspan="2" scope="row">Campus:</th>
<td class="dddefault">Reynolda Campus  (UG)</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


item[i+1]:  
<table class="datadisplaytable" summary="This table lists the scheduled meeting times and assigned instructors for this class.."><caption class="captiontext">Scheduled Meeting Times</caption>
<tbody><tr>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Type</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Time</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Days</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Where</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Date Range</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Schedule Type</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Instructors</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dddefault">Class</td>
<td class="dddefault">12:30 pm - 1:45 pm</td>
<td class="dddefault">MWF</td>
<td class="dddefault">Carswell Hall 101</td>
<td class="dddefault">Jan 13, 2015 - May 07, 2015</td>
<td class="dddefault">Lecture</td>
<td class="dddefault">Jason Dale  Gaddis (<abbr title="Primary">P</abbr>)<a href="mailto:gaddisjd@wfu.edu" target="Jason D. Gaddis"><img align="middle" alt="E-mail" border="0" class="headerImg" height="28" hspace="0" name="web_email" src="/wtlgifs/web_email.gif" title="E-mail" vspace="0" width="28"/></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I'd rely on something unique about the tables. For example, on `summary` attribute:

```
summaries = set()
tables = []

for table in soup.find_all("table", {"class": "datadisplaytable"}):
    summary = table['summary']
    if summary not in summaries:
        summaries.add(summary)
        tables.append(table)
```